# XPath built-in function and use thereof with lxml

Tags: python, xml, xpath, lxml

Here is a simple code example I am trying.

```
from lxml import etree

myXML = etree.XML('''\
  <registers part="FXLS8471Q">
    <register fxblock="Newfx">
      <regname>STATUS_NEW</regname>
      <regnamelong/>
      <type>R</type>
      <address>00</address>
      <defaulthex>00</defaulthex>
      <field>
        <number>7</number>
        <name>F_STATUS</name>
        <width>8</width>
        <reset>00000000</reset>
      </field>
    </register>
  </registers>
    ''')

def hello(context, a):
    return "Hello %s" % a

ns = etree.FunctionNamespace(None)
ns['hello'] = hello

print(myXML.xpath("hello('Dr. Falken')"))
print(myXML.xpath('hello(string(regname))'))
```

I am puzzled as to why the last statement does not print what I expect (STATUS_NEW). How can I tell if there are incompatibility issues with my Python 2.7 and site-packages? Or is there some coding error?

Are all XPath built-in functions supported with lxml and if not, can someone point me to what subset of them is supported? I am using lxml 3.2.1.

Thanks,
Jayaram

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The correct XPath expression is `//regname` or `/registers/register/regname`:

```
print(myXML.xpath('hello(string(//regname))'))
```